# Having trouble seeing what's wrong with my syntax here (SP)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

It is bringing up an error on line 'Select @RowCount = 1'

```
declare @RowCount int
declare @MaxRows int
declare @CommonImportID bigint
declare @UserName3

select @RowCount = 1;
select @MaxRows = count(*) from import.commonImport;

while @RowCount <= @MaxRows
begin
EXEC [import].[spExecuteMainProcedure]
     @CommonImportID = 2814,
     @UserName3 = N'dTrunley'
select @CommonImportID = @CommonImportID + 1;
select @RowCount = @RowCount + 1;
end
```

Just really struggling to see what I've done wrong. Probably something really basic.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define a data type here:

```
declare @UserName3
```

Should probably be something like:

```
declare @UserName3 nvarchar(8)
```

Comment: ...I'm literally retarded. Thanks for that. Just having one of those days

Comment: @user1016253 - No worries. We all have times where we can't see what's staring us in the face. Take a break.